# Problem with lftp command at 0 [Connecting...]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, connection, lftp

i have problem **`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]** when  lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow false;set ftp:use-mlsd on;debug" -u user,pass host . but there are no problems from another host

Comment: hosting caught a ban at the provider level, the issue is closed